# ¿Por qué la función me modifica una fila de la matriz y a otra no le hace nada?

Tags: python-3.x, matrices, numpy

Buenas noches a todas y todos. Me encuentro haciendo una calculadora de raíces y sistemas de ecuaciones y tengo que hacer una función que pueda pivotear las matrices (lograr que todos los elementos de la diagonal principal sean distintos de cero).

Para lograr esto, tengo en mente analizar las columnas y encontrar el elemento más grande, para después identificar la fila asociada a este elemento y hacer un intercambio de filas (fila que contiene el elemento de la diagonal principal y fila que contiene el elemento más grande dentro de la columna a analizar). Al correr el programa este me identifica correctamente el elemento más grande y crea dos variables donde almaceno las filas que se deben intercambiar.

El problema es que al momento de ejecutarse la última parte sucede un bug o algo que no logro entender y los resultados obtenidos no son los esperados. Si alguien pudiera orientarme estaría muy agradecido. Para que se entienda mejor la situación adjuntaré el código de la función y la primera iteración de la función. De antemano, muchas gracias !

---

```
def pivotear(matrix):
matriz=np.array(matrix)
size=matriz.shape
n=size[0]
i=0
while i<n:
    print(matriz)
    masGrande=matriz[i,i]
    fila=i
    j=0
    while j<n:
        if j==i:
            j=j+1
            if j==n:
                break
        analizar=matriz[j,i]
        if analizar>masGrande:
            masGrande=analizar
            fila=j
        j=j+1
    if matriz[i,i]==masGrande:
        i=i+1
    else:
        cambio=matriz[fila,:]
        print(cambio)
        cambiar=matriz[i,:]
        print(cambiar)
        matriz[i,:]=cambio
        matriz[fila,:]=cambiar
        i=i+1
return matriz
```

---

```
[[1 0 6 8]
 [-4 0 3 4]
 [1 3 7 3]
 [2 -1 3 0]]
[2 -1 3 0]
[1 0 6 8]
[[2 -1 3 0]
 [-4 0 3 4]
 [1 3 7 3]
 [2 -1 3 0]]
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la matriz con que prueba? Si sabes cual es el resultado correcto, colocalo también para chequear tu código

Comment: Tienes razón, no lo he mencionado. La matriz de prueba es la primera que sale bajo el código: [[1 0 6 8],[-4 0 3 4],[1 3 7 3],[2 -1 3 0]]. Después de mostrar la matriz de prueba, salen dos líneas donde el programa efectivamente me detecta y almacena las filas que deben permutarse, pero algo sucede que solo una se permuta y la otra queda igual.